# SSH keys in authorized keys, but still getting "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I already have added my `id_rsa.pub` key into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of `ubuntu` user on my EC2 instance, but I still not able to connect without providing a key file (the downloaded `.pem` file from Amazon console). I'm getting the message: "Permission denied (publickey).". I'm sure that I've added the right key because is the same I use in another services like Github, CloudControl and Bitbucket.

Comment: What is the command you use to ssh to your EC2 instance?

Comment: `ssh ubuntu@<elastic ip>` (trying this way) but only works specifying a key `ssh ubuntu@<elastic ip> -i C:\path\to\my\key.pem`. I'm on Windows BTW.

Comment: Did you try `ssh ubuntu@<elastic ip> -i C:\path\to\id_rsa` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first create an additional (non-root) user and repeat your authorized_keys exercise, I recall limitations on the lower sshd level about root-level logins using public keys. Follow the sequence here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html

Comment: Not work for me. Followed the steps replacing `newuser` by `git`, then pasted the id_rsa.pub value of my machine in the authorized_keys file, then tried to access with `ssh git@<elastic-ip>`, but received Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: you might want to inspect ssh's output when adding the options -vvv for super-verbose reporting as this gives more insights on the real reason of the failure.